# Unbound classpath variable in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

When I started eclipse for the first time today the Problems window flooded with over 90 "unbound classpath variable" errors. For example

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath variable: 'ANT_HOME/lib/ant.jar' in project 'SBApp-Dev-2014q3'    SBApp-Dev-2014q3        Build path  Build Path Problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="ANT_HOME/lib/ant.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

I also have eclipse classpath variable called ANT_HOME which targets to C:/Apps/apache-ant-1.9.4. The lib/ant.jar resides in that directory.

Any idea what could it be?

Comment: Clean and Build the workspace?